# How to restore a 10.1 backup to an iPhone with 10.0.2 without updating to the newest iOS available on itunes (currently 10.2)?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, software-update

Specifically, my backup is for 10.1 but the existing iOS on the phone is 10.0.2. When I plug into iTunes, it does not even show my backup from the "Restore Backup" option.

While I would prefer to have the full backup, the firmware is the most important to me. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Backup and restore doesn't change firmware, only user data. That is how iTunes is designed.

Same with the regression, backups do not go backwards. [Only forwards. You can restore a backup from an older version to a newer version of iOS.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27004/can-i-restore-an-iphone-backup-taken-from-a-previous-ios-version-or-is-there-a)

Best case, you export the data to a computer or online service and find a way to jailbreak or buy a device with the older OS. Then you could import the data as opposed to the backup.

Also see:

- [Can I install any iOS version I wish by picking and choosing which firmware to restore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r)

Comment: Thanks, i know the restore doesn't allow for past ioS versions, but I was wondering if since my backup is from 10.1 and the phone i am trying to restore to is 10.0.2, is there a way for the .0.2 phone restore the 10.1 backup rather than the current update of 10.2? 

This could be a stupid question, but per your comment, I'm assuming since the backup version was newer than the current ios itunes did not recognize it as a compatible option to restore. With the "OPT" + Restore, it allows for .ipa files, if apple still allows sign in. Is there no way round about that with

Comment: with the "OPT" + Restore, I can choose .ipa files, but apple no longer permits predated versions prior to 10.2. I was wondering if since the backup has the pre-existing 10.1 firmware, if there was a roundabout way to install that on the 10.0.2 phone (as technically it is a newer version than the one the phone currently has).

Comment: You are correct @sdenning , if you didn't restore that older version and cache the signing keys for your specific device on iTunes and didn't upgrade a restore to same old iOS works usually. Once you upgrade, those signing keys are discarded by design.